# Два сайта на одном локальном компьютере ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

Постоянно забываю как это делать решил задать вопрос здесь, чтобы после можно было его найти.

Как я делаю:

> sudo gedit /etc/hosts

добавляю строчку в открывшемся файле

> 127.0.0.1 test.loc www.test.loc

сохраняем, далее:

> sudo gedit /etc/apache2/conf.d/custom/vhosts

добавляем следующее

```
<VirtualHost *:80>ServerName test.locServerAlias test.locDocumentRoot "/home/www-data/www/test/www"ScriptAlias /cgi/ "/home/www-data/www/test/cgi-bin/"ErrorLog /home/www-data/www/test/error.logCustomLog /home/www-data/www/test/access.log common</VirtualHost>
```

создаю в "/home/www-data/www" "/home/www-data/www/test/www" c правами 777в результате ввода в браузере http://www.test.loc/ я должен попасть на страничку

> /home/www-data/www/test/www/index.php

но видимо я что то упускаю, т.к. открывается другая страница.

вот что у меня БЫЛО в vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>ServerName test.locServerAlias test.locDocumentRoot "/home/www-data/www/test/www"ScriptAlias /cgi/ "/home/www-data/www/test/cgi-bin/"ErrorLog /home/www-data/www/test/error.logCustomLog /home/www-data/www/test/access.log common</VirtualHost>
```

и hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost127.0.1.1   alexander-A17127.0.0.1 test.loc www.test.loc
```

всё что не работает перенаправляется на skaz-gorod.loc (в адресной строке адрес не меняется), что я делаю не так?

пользователя www-data добавил в группу пользователя которым являюсь (это не безопасно но мне не страшно :) )Доработал напильником:

вот что у меня СТАЛО в vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5>ServerName test.locServerAlias test.locDocumentRoot "/home/www-data/www/test/www"ScriptAlias /cgi/ "/home/www-data/www/test/cgi-bin/"ErrorLog /home/www-data/www/test/error.logCustomLog /home/www-data/www/test/access.log common</VirtualHost>
```

и hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost127.0.1.1   alexander-A17127.0.0.5   test.loc www.test.loc
```

после сайт открывался с ошибкой:

> ```
> Internal Server ErrorThe server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> ```
>
> unable to complete your request.
>
> ```
> Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and
> ```
>
> inform them of the time the erroroccurred, and anything you might havedone that may have caused the error.
>
> ```
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> ```
>
> log.
>
> ```
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.5 Port 80
> ```

а в логах писал:

> ```
> [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /home/www-data/www/test/www/.htaccess:
> ```
>
> Invalid command 'RewriteEngine',perhaps misspelled or defined by amodule not included in the serverconfiguration

Ошибка говорит, что не включен модуль Апача rewrite

Решается просто:

> sudo a2enmod rewrite
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

УРА ЗАРАБОТАЛО!

Comment: [Тут уже обсуждалось создание виртуальных хостов Apache...][1]  [1]: http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/4081/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-apache2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для КАЖДОГО вирт.хоста

```
1. sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/site_name2. sudo gedit (nano, vi, etc. - нужное подчеркнуть) /etc/apache2/sites-available/site_name<VirtualHost *:80>ServerAdmin admin@mail.local   #почта админа#то, что увидят посетителиDocumentRoot /home/user/sites/site_name/www<Directory />    Options FollowSymLinks    AllowOverride None</Directory>#то, что НЕ увидят посетители (например логи сайта) и права на папку<Directory /home/user/sites/site_name/>    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews    AllowOverride None    Order allow,deny    allow from all</Directory>ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">    AllowOverride None    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory>#лог ошибок сайтаErrorLog /home/user/sites/site_name/logs/error.log# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,# alert, emerg.LogLevel warn#лог доступа сайтаCustomLog /home/user/sites/site_name/access.log combinedAlias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks    AllowOverride None    Order deny,allow    Deny from all    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128</Directory>
```

</VirtualHost>

```
4. sudo a2dissite default            #отключить дефолтный сайт5. sudo a2ensite site_name           #подключить свой сайт6. sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart  #рестарт апача для полноты ощущений;)7. прописАть IP сайта на DNS-сервере (если локально - то файл /etc/hots привести к виду типа "127.0.0.1       localhost site_name www.site_name")
```

Взято [ТУТ](http://www.yaap.info/page/ustanovka-i-nastrojka-lamp-linuxapachemysqlphp-v-ubuntu) [ТУТ](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apachemysqlphp) [ТУТ](http://www.sdelaysite.com/besplatnoe-po/ustanovka-apache-php-mysql-ubuntu-2)

Ах, да.... чуть не забыл самое интересное... у пользователя www-data должны быть полные права на папку /home/user/sites/site_name/ (*для конкретно ЭТОГО примера* виртуального хоста). Вообще, папку с сайтом можно положить куда угодно, главное, чтоб на момент запуска Apace2 она была доступна по прописанному адресу.

**UPD**

Для полноты картины name-based виртуального хоста можно (или нужно) проверить в ports.conf наличие и раскоментированность

```
NameVirtualHost *:80Listen 80
```

и там же прописать что-то типа

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  DocumentRoot /home/user/sites/site_name/www  ServerName site_name</VirtualHost><VirtualHost *:80>  DocumentRoot /home/user/sites/site_name-1/www  ServerName site_name-1</VirtualHost>
```

по блоку для каждого сайта (тут - `site_name` и `site_name-1`). И можна размещать на одном IP столько сайтов, сколько сервер и канал потянут ;)

Comment: Небольшое добавление:  Я бы все-таки оставил в покое адрес 127.0.0.1, и разместил бы свои сайты на следующих за ним адресах (127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3).